# How to plot only within a range defined by x number of bars?

Tags: plot, pine-script

I understand that I can contingently plot on the chart using range of date and time values.

However, I would like to be able to plot using a ***specific number of candlesticks***.

For example, I would like to be able to say something like

```
// Within the most recent 10 bars
// If close[0] > close[1]
// plotshape()
```

I have tried implementing numerous variations using `barstate.isrealtime` or `barstate.islast` but I keep running into limitations.

One major problem is that, although `bar_index[#]` works by indexing backwards from **the most recent bar**, the value of `bar_index[10]` is not 10 but some number in the thousands (depending on the timeframe of the chart — for me its Daily = 2,616 candles, 1hr = 6,217 candles, 15m = 5,222, etc.).  In other words, it counts the number of bars from **the oldest bar** available.

Since referencing of the bars (starting from most recent) and the index values (starting from the oldest) are conflicting--due to counting from opposite ends--I am not sure how to specify: plotshape() for the most recent 10 bars.

I am also running into trouble due to the fact that `bar_index[0]` occurs every single iteration of the chart's timeframe--so I am getting caught in recursive calculations when trying to do `bar_index[0]-bar_index[10]`.

It seems that what I need is something like `bar_index.islast[10]`

The reason that I would like to call a plotshape() based on the **number of specified candles** versus **since x date/time** (or **within date range (x,y)**), is because I want my indicator to function properly regardless of which timeframe my chart is displaying:

If I am showing a monthly chart, I want to plot across the last 10 monthly bars; If I am showing a daily chart, I want to plot across the last 10 daily bars; etc.

If I am forced to use a date range, then this functionality breaks down, since I will be shown increasingly more bars for smaller timeframes.

**Caveat****
I am able to ***kinda*** make this work by specifying the number of bars from the oldest candlestick by stating something like:

`bar_index > 2600 ? color=color.black : na`

However, given the fact that every single time frame displays a different number of bars, this is not a workable solution for me.

Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE**
I have been hunting around and and found that the functionality I desire is already built into the `show_last` argument of the various plot()functoins.

Ill leave my question posted, in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** I have been hunting around and and found that the functionality I desire is already built into the `show_last = int` argument of the various `plot()` functions.

I'll leave my question posted, in case it helps someone else.